# How do I call live event with blur together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some question with these events.

My code is something like this:

```
dialogX.find('#inputExample').blur(function() { 
    var button = $(this).parent().find('#buttonExample');

    if(!(button.is(':clicked'))) //this doesn't work, just test
        button.hide();                                  
});

dialogX.find('#buttonExample').live('click', function() {
    alert('Test!');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The question is, when I'm on input (#inputExample) and later click on button (#buttonExample), blur is called and live event is never called.

***I have to use live instead of on, because JQuery version.

Someone could help me?

Comment: can you please be more clear about what do you want the code to do

Comment: I need that when I type something in the input and later click on the button (save), the live event be called instead of blur.

Comment: They should both be called. When you click on the button, you remove focus from the input, so its blur event should be called.

Comment: Can you make a stack snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dialogX.find('#inputExample').blur(function() { 
    var button = $(this).parent().find('#buttonExample');

    if(disableBlur)
        button.hide();                                  
});
var disableBlur = false;
dialogX.live('mousedown', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).prop('id')=='buttonExample')
        disableBlur = true;
    else
        disableBlur = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks vinayakj, this works. I realized that (.live('click') event dosn't work right, but (live('mousedown') works. Thanks everyone.